# Admission SNS 2020-2021 (prove that a certain function is a homeomorphism)

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

> Consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as
> $$f(x,y)=\left(6x+(4+x^2+y^2/2)^{1/2},8y+\operatorname{log}(1+y^2)+\operatorname{arctan}(x)\right)$$
>
> i) Prove that the preimage of a compact set through $f$ is compact
>
> ii) prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2 $ to
> $\mathbb{R}^2$

*(Problem from admission SNS, IV year, 2021-2022, you can find the original text online.)*

I'm trying to solve some exercises from the SNS admission at the IV year. There are no solutions available so I'm asking feedback and help on this platform. Fyi, these exercises are aimed to an undergrad who has just finished its degree, so no advanced topics are required supposedly. Final remark, I'm not smart and maybe this is easy, but nevertheless I'm giving it a go.

I spent a couple of hours  on it and I have zero practical ideas on how to tackle it.
For the first point i wondered if you could prove that the preimage of a bound set is bounded but I couldn't find any $\geq$ estimate for $f$.
For the second point, I really have no idea on how to do it, I'm pretty sure you can't just exhibit the inverse.

So I'm asking:

1. If someone has any hint
2. If someone has any willing to give me a sketch of solution

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the second question, if you know it, you can use the global inversion theorem of Hadamard-Lévy

Comment: For 1: by continuity, the preimage of a closed set is closed. It remains to show that the preimage of a bounded set is bounded. You can do this by hand (the computations seem a bit messy but feasible).
For 2: as suggested above, you will need to use the inverse function Theorem. First, use it to show that $f$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image. Then, show that the image of $f$ is both closed and open (this will presumably rely on Question 1) and conclude by connectedness that the image is all of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: I've never heard of that theorem, so thanks. Regarding the boundedness of the preimage, I tried to see if I could say $|f_1(x,y)|\geq k+C|(x,y)|, |f_2(x,y)|\geq k'+C'|(x,y)|$, but I couldn't find any way to do it. Is this the only way to prove this boundedness or there are other ways?

Comment: If you've never heard about local inversion, this exercise is not for you yet, unless you are a magician an know how to prove injection without any tools (yes it happens)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proposition of answers:

1. $f$ is obviously continuous, I think that is no problem for you, hence we just need to show that the preimage of a bounded subset is bounded.

If $\|f(x,y)\|_\infty < M$, then $|8y + \ln(1+y^2) + \arctan(x)| < 8 |y| + \ln (1+y^2) + \frac{\pi}{2}$ is bounded, thus $|y|$ is bounded, and $6x + |x|$ is bounded, so $x$ is bounded, hence the presage of a bounded set is bounded.

2. There exists a theorem by Hadamard-Lévy that states:

> **Theorem:** Let $f \in \mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$, then the following proposition are equivalent:
>
> - $f$ is a $\mathcal{C}^1$-diffeomorphism.
> - $f$ is proper and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $df_x$ is non-singular.

What "proper" means is that $\lim\limits_{\|x \| \to \infty} \| f(x) \| = \infty$, which is equivalent to the preimage of a compact is compact since $f$ is continuous.

So we only need to prove that $df$ is invertible everywhere.
$$df_{(x,y)} = \begin{pmatrix} 
6 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{4 + x^2 +\frac{y^2}{2}}} & \frac{1}{1 +x^2}\\
\frac{y}{2\sqrt{4 + x^2 +\frac{y^2}{2}}} & 8 + \frac{2y}{1+y^2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\det df_{(x,y}) = \left( 6 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{4 + x^2 +\frac{y^2}{2}}} \right) \left( 8 + \frac{2y}{1+y^2} \right) - \frac{1}{1 +x^2}\frac{y}{2\sqrt{4 + x^2 +\frac{y^2}{2}}} > 5\cdot 6 - 1 >0$$
So the condition is filled, hence $f$ is a diffeomorphism, thus an homeo.

**Other option**: If you can't use this theorem, use connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (this is what the proof uses).

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I've got only one question, about the passage
 "$|8y + \ln(1+y^2) + \arctan(x)| < 8 |y| + \ln (1+y^2) + \frac{\pi}{2}$, then |y| is bounded". 
In this inequality I know that the left term is bounded, why can I conclude that the |y| is bounded? Shouldn't I try to find an inequality like $|8y + \ln(1+y^2) + \arctan(x)| >\mathrm{sth}$?

Comment: because $\ln(1+y^2) = o(y)$

Comment: @Traincopter but yes you should find such an inequality, this will make it clearer (I went fast)

Comment: Yes to be sincere I don't think I understood it, but it's my fault.
Anyway I saw that proving that $\lim\limits_{\|x \| \to \infty} \| f(x) \| = \infty$ is feasible, you just notice that $\| f(x) \|^2\sim 37x^2+\frac{129}{2}y^2+12x\sqrt{4+x^2+\frac{y^2}{2}}$ 
If $x>0: \ \| f(x) \| \longrightarrow \infty$ 
If $x<0: \  12x\sqrt{4+x^2+\frac{y^2}{2}} \geq 12x\left(\left(|x|+\frac{|y|}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \frac{4}{\sqrt{(x^2+\frac{y^2}{2}})}+o(\frac{4}{(x^2+\frac{y^2}{2})})\right) $ and so even in this case $\| f(x) \| \longrightarrow \infty$ (I hope there aren't errors)

Comment: @Traincopter yes maybe this way is easier, but are you sure you did not Forget terms in $xy$? Plus your fonction has two variables, not just $x$. You will take less risks by properly showing that the preimage of a bounded set is bounded.

Comment: In the calculation the only one I saw it wasn't o(x^2+y^2) was the term $ 12x\sqrt{4+x^2+\frac{y^2}{2} }$. Regarding the risk I took, I undestand, it took me quite a lot of time to sort out the limit (assuming it's correct)